# Can't run `node start` through npm script, but running on terminal runs just fine

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have a simple project launching a node server in an app.js file in my src directory.

Project structure as follows:

- package.json
- src

  - app.js

my package.json contains

```
  1 { 
  2   "name": "backend", 
  3   "version": "1.0.0", 
  4   "description": "", 
  5   "main": "src/app.js", 
  6   "scripts": { 
  7     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1", 
  8     "start": "node ./src/app.js" 
  9   }, 
 10   "author": "my name", 
 11   "license": "ISC" 
 12 }
```

When running `npm start` I get the following error:

```
> backend@1.0.0 start
> node ./src/app.js

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:930
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/myname/dev/produce/personal/healthapp/backend/src/app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:927:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:772:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Running `node src/app.js` from the project root directory (same as package.json) works fine, however

Comment: When you run the command from the CLI, are you in the same directory as package.json?

Comment: When you say "project root directory", are you referring to `/Users/myname/dev/produce/personal/healthapp/backend`?

Comment: @AlexCollette yes

Comment: @CherryDT yes  I am

Comment: Try running `node /Users/myname/dev/produce/personal/healthapp/backend/src/app.js`. Also, while in the project root, show us the result of `pwd`

Comment: Please also go to the directory containing app.js and post the output of `pwd`

Comment: @AlexCollette  `node <fullpath>` gave me the same error... `pwd` produces `/Users/myname/dev/produce/personal/healthapp/backend`

Comment: @derpirscher `pwd` in the src folder produces `/Users/myname/dev/produce/personal/healthapp/backend/src`

Comment: Is package.json in the src folder?

Comment: Show me the result of `readlink -f src/app.js`

Comment: figured it out, i mistakenly wrote `app,js` instead of `app.js` and I guess i couldn't notice the difference on my terminal font. Tabbing would autocomplete from the CLI so I never noticed it. Thanks for bearing with me.